# Can 2 magnets crush something with their force?

Tags: electromagnetism

Say we have 2 magnets facing the same way with same charge, and we have a rock tied from the celling and to the ground so the rock dose not move away. Since the 2 magnets are repealing each other, if they move closer would the force of the magnets repealing break the rock?
Assume the rock is no bigger than a rice grain or an eraser in a pencil.

Comment: If the magnets attract each other and you put something between them, that thing can certainly be crushed, as the victims of various MRI-related accidents will surely tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the "rock" is something that's also magnetic. Most rocks aren't, and the magnetic force passes right through them as if they aren't there.

But if you replace that rock with something magnetic (and conductive helps), sure, with enough force [you'll crush it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2TDXKfBaMQ).